# How to align ComboBox item to right after the separator

Tags: wpf, combobox, styles, controltemplate, datatrigger

Originally, the `ComboBox` item is aligned to left. I add an separator to the `ComboBox` and the separator will be visible whenever a null value of data binding is presented. I would like to align the `ComboBox` items which are after the separator to right. Is that possible to make it?

```
<cc:TogglingComboBox  FontSize="11" Grid.Column="1" InitialDisplayItem="10"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" SelectedValue="{Binding Dye}"  ItemsSource="{Binding Dyes}" Margin="5,3,5,0">
<ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>                                 
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ComboBoxItem}}">
    <Style.Triggers>

        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding}" Value="{x:Null}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
                        <Separator HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" IsEnabled="False"/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
</ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Comment: I think you can't to find out where a concrete element is, so I suggest you to use StyleSelector and check where an element is in the code by yourself (before or after null)

Comment: I'm not so sure since i m new to wpf. How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DataContext` for the `ComboBoxItem` is an object of some collection. As I see, your `Separator` template will be applied every time when item of source the collection is null. If you know that there are fixed numbers of null-value items in your collection (1, for example), you can write `Converter`.

Here an example:

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="ComboBoxWithSeparator.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ComboBoxWithSeparator"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <local:MyConverter x:Key="MyConverter" />
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ComboBoxItem}}">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MyConverter}">
                            <Binding />
                            <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ComboBox}" Path="ItemsSource" />
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter> 
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding}" Value="{x:Null}">
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
                                    <Separator HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" IsEnabled="False"/>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                  Width="250"
                  Height="25"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        List<string> a = new List<string>()
        {
            "one",
            "two",
            "three",
            "four",
            "five",
            null,
            "seven",
            "eight",
            "nine",
            "ten"
        };
        DataContext = a;
    }
}
public class MyConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{

    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {

        string s = (string)values[0];
        IEnumerable<string> array = (IEnumerable<string>)values[1];

        if (s == null)
            return HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;

        foreach (string item in array)
        {
            if (s == item)
                return HorizontalAlignment.Left;
            if (item == null)
                return HorizontalAlignment.Right;
        }

        return HorizontalAlignment.Left;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And the result:

[image: ComboBox items are aligned to the right after the separator]

Comment: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Object]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.String]'. 
at this line of code "IEnumerable<string> array = (IEnumerable<string>)values[1];"

Comment: I wrote an example, and I send as a DataContext the List<string>. In your case, you could change those IEnumerable to your List<Object> and cast them as you want.

Comment: Please look at this example : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11680660/combobox-show-and-hide-combobox-items-in-wpf . The example is the custom ComboBox which can show and hide the ComboBox item. So whenever the More button is clicked, the remaining ComboBox item will be displayed. But I would like to add in the Separator between the remaining items and after the initial display items. Those remaining items will be aligned to right whereas the initial display item is still remain align to left. The example is the custom ComboBox inherit from ComboBox. Is that possible to achieve that?

Comment: Write sample project that consist of this ComboBox with data and share it to me (skydrive for example), I take a look on it and think about your problem.

Comment: https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=268424066586F1F7!963
Shared! The file name is WpfApplication1

Comment: I don't know why, but Style is not applied to the ComboBoxItems which are generated. I gave you an idea - to use Converter. try to accomplish it.

Comment: The Separator can't be added into the Generic.xaml ?

Comment: It can be added, but its take too much time to solve your problem.

Comment: is ok as long as can create a custom combobox which has a Separator and the items after Separator will align to right. 
But I have no idea on how to continue with the current state now. Your help is appreciated!